# What is the equivalent of Java CLASSPATH in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to run ruby programs from anywhere.
I think I have understood it is RUBYLIB. But I can't make it work. Could you give examples ?

Comment: To the none-java people that are rubyists: What is the CLASSPATH in java? :)

Comment: CLASSPATH is the ; or : separated list of directories containing *.class files or libraries (containing *.class files) for the Java VM to resolve dependencies when a class is loaded.

Comment: I take the question to mean that in Java there are a set of annoying classpath "issues."  What corresponds to classpath problems in Ruby?  Missing gems/what?  still not really answered well, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option **-S** which looks for the script using PATH environment variable.

for example doing:

```
ruby -S some_script
```

Will look for the some_script in current operating system PATH environment variable.

**Update**: If your script requires other files then use the following statement:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "name_of_required_file")
```

instead of:

```
require "name_of_required_path"
```

Comment: Ok, the aforementioned file "some_script" is now correctly found by ruby (thx!), but this file also contains a 'require 'foo'", that is not loaded (LoadError). It resides in the same directory as the first script...

Any idea ?

Comment: To get your required file included you can do the following
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "name_of_required_file")

Comment: The comment code remove 2 underscores before and after the file it should be xxFILExx where x is an underscore

Comment: Yes Steve's solution should work. I have updated the post to have it.

Answer (score 5):

- You need to manupulate the load path `$LOAD_PATH ($:)`
- This is done with `-I directories` (Directories are separated by a `:` on Unix-like systems and by a `;` on DOS/Windows systems.)
- You could add `-I` switches to `RUBYOPT` (`$SAFE` must be 0)
- Or with `RUBYLIB` (`$SAFE` must be 0 also) which contains search paths.
- `RUBYPATH` also changes search path for Ruby programs.
- For environment variables, make sure they are proper set or exported so the Ruby VM sees them. You could add a debug print in the ruby.bat or ruby.sh.
- Check your `$SAFE` setting. If you don't know about it, then its probably fine.

I allways set `RUBYLIB` and `RUBYPATH` to my loadpath and add the `-S` option to the interpreter call.